# How to enable Siri to Speak and write Tamil In Mac book and iPhone 7

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-configurator, iphone-upgrade-program

I have downloaded a software linguist. This software is able to translate the in writing. Can Siri be linked to this software to read and write Tamil?

Comment: cool idea!  :) have you tried using a text translator of some type and then "speaking in English" the text words in a different language?